# Change the styling of a js file reading from a text file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML file that is using a javascript file reading from a text file. I have the text of the text file displaying in my html file but I want to be able to style it with css. How would this be done? Im not the greatest at this and still learning so don't be afraid to dumb it down lol

Not sure where to start to be honest

Heres the HTML

```
<html>  

<head>  

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">  

<script src="overlay.js"></script>  

</head>  

<body>  
</body>  

</html>
```

heres the JS (keep in mind that 'filename' would be the name of my text file)

```
new XMLHttpRequest();


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

xhr.open('GET', 'filename', false);

xhr.onload = function (){

    document.write( xhr.responseText );

};

xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: You can't style plain text... you can style HTML with CSS. It depends what is inside the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `document.write` after the page finished will rewrite the entire page, making your styling and such go away.

Instead, set your text on an element with `textContent`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

xhr.open('GET', 'filename', false);

xhr.onload = function (){

    document.querySelector('body').textContent = xhr.responseText;

};

xhr.send(null);
```